# MongoDB : Can't compare NumberInt?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-shell

[image]

Why `NumberInt(1) == NumberInt(1) // false` ?

Background: I have written MongoDB script to compare the documents on some fields. After few hours digging I found that `NumberInt` comparison not working as I expected.

What's way to compare number ? I am doing:

[image]

Comment: _I have written MongoDB script to compare the documents on some fields. After few hours digging I found that NumberInt comparison not working as I expected._ Please share that script.

Comment: In MongoDB queries, numbers are compared using the comparison operators, like $eq, $gte, etc. For example, if you have a document `{ n: NumberInt(1) }` in a collection, you can query it as `db.test.find( { n: NumberInt(1) } )`, to get the document.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing the comparison correctly. MongoDB shell is essentially an interactive javascript shell. If you do `typeof NumberInt(1)` in the shell it will tell you it's an object. So, you can't really expect an object to be equal to another object. That's why `NumberInt(1) == NumberInt(1) => false`.

Since you're interested in comparing only the values, a `.value` function might have helped here. But a quick check of the properties of the object yields nothing:

```
> Object.keys(NumberInt(1))
[ ]
> Object.getOwnPropertyNames(NumberInt(1))
[ ]
```

As you can see, there isn't any property that can be used to know the value of the object. As the doc says, `NumberInt` is just a constructor/wrapper for creating 32-bit integers as mongo shell treats all numbers as floating-point values by default.